# Dynamic array of compound type

Tags: c++, new-operator

Is it possible to make the same thing without type alias?

```
    void f()
    {
        typedef char Str[16];
        int n=256;
        Str** p = new Str*[n];
        delete[] p;
    }
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
    // char(**p)[16] = new char(*[n])[16]; // error
    // char(**p)[16] = new (char(*[n])[16]); // error
```

Comment: You should just use `std::vector<std::array<char, 16>>`.

Comment: @n314159 That's an analogue for `new Str[n]`, not `new Str*[n]`. (All the more reason to make things clearer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want to create a dynamic array where the element type is `char (*)[16]`. No, it can't be done without a type alias. In order to use a dynamic extent, you need to use the following form of a *new-expression* (C++17 [expr.new]/1):

> `::`(opt) `new` *new-placement*(opt) *new-type-id* *new-initializer*(opt)

But if you look at the definitions of *new-type-id*, *new-declarator*, and *noptr-new-declarator*, you see that parentheses are not allowed for altering operator precedence. Thus, we can't explicitly write down the desired type in this context.

Best solution: use `std::vector`. If you can't do that (maybe you are targeting some very limited freestanding implementation) then use the typedef.